# Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, service-worker

The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE (index):1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Code for template.js root file

```
export default ({ markup, css }) => {
  return `<!doctype html>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>MERN Marketplace</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
          <style>
              a{
                text-decoration: none
              }
          </style>
          <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
        </head>
        <body style="margin:0">
            <div id="root">${markup}</div>
          <style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>

          <script id="stripe-js" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" async></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
          <script>
          if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function() { 
              console.log("Service Worker Registered"); 
            });
          }
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>`;
};
```

Comment: Service Workers won't work on an HTTP site, even locally, you have to use something like https://ngrok.com in order to test locally on a https site

Comment: Thanks for you comment but I know that There's an exception to the HTTPS requirement in place to facilitate local development: if you access your page and service worker script via http://localhost[:port], or via http://127.x.y.z[:port], then service workers should be enabled without any further actions.

Comment: There is one annoyance that might be the problem here. If 404 is returned, you still get MIME type ('text/html') error. Just spent an hour dealing with precisely this issue :( Make sure that the path to the worker resolves relative to the html doc that sources your compiled js.

Answer (score -1):

On my personal experience, I just ensured the **sw.js** file is in the same folder as **index.html**.